# root@localhost password set with Ansible mysql_user module doesn't work

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ansible

I have the following playbook:

```
- hosts: myserver
  vars:
    mysql_root_password: foobarbaz

[...]

tasks:

  [...]

  - name: update mysql root password for all root accounts
      mysql_user: name=root host={{ item }} password={{ mysql_root_password }} priv=*.*:ALL,GRANT
      with_items:
        - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
        - 127.0.0.1
        - ::1
        - "localhost"
      become: true
      tags: mysql

  [...]

  # I've ommitted the tasks to install the mysql packages, 
  # store the password in /root/.my.cnf and restart the server)
```

The problem is the desired pasword is correctly saved in mysql.user for 127.0.0.1, ::1 and the hostname **but not** for localhost, i.e.

```
mysql> select host,user,authentication_string from user;
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user             | authentication_string                     |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root             |                                           |
| localhost | mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | *DA57FEBA9C5C5119186DB8834C7B83216E450117 |
| ubuntu    | root             | *8C5206E23A3B76002AA6E152691F5C5D7ABC31F9 |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             | *8C5206E23A3B76002AA6E152691F5C5D7ABC31F9 |
| ::1       | root             | *8C5206E23A3B76002AA6E152691F5C5D7ABC31F9 |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Where *8C52... is the encrypted password:

```
mysql> select password('foobarbaz');
+-------------------------------------------+
| password('foobarbaz')                     |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *8C5206E23A3B76002AA6E152691F5C5D7ABC31F9 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Therefore, this fails:

```
william@ubuntu:/etc/mysql$ mysql -u root --password=foobarbaz
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

and also if I use sudo, I can connect to mysql as root using any password or none.

To put it another way, this ansible command doesn't do anything, but if I use any other user or host it works.

```
ansible myserver -m mysql_user -a "name=root host=localhost password=foobarbaz priv=*.*:ALL,GRANT" -b
myserver | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": true,
    "user": "root"
}
```

MySQL: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Ansible 2.1.2.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cause is this limitation of the Ansible [mysql_user module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mysql_user_module.html):

> Currently, there is only support for the mysql_native_password
>   encryted password hash module.

You can install MySQL packages with or without specifying a root password.

**Installation with root password**

With a password, the root@localhost login uses [mysql_native_password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/native-authentication-plugin.html), which is the [password hashing method introduced in MySQL 4.1.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-hashing.html), where passwords are 41 bytes long beginning with a single asterisk, and the [`password()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function generates the hash.

```
mysql> select host,user,authentication_string,plugin from mysql.user;
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| host      | user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| localhost | root             | *9B500343BC52E2911172EB52AE5CF4847604C6E5 | mysql_native_password |
| localhost | mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | *DA57FEBA9C5C5119186DB8834C7B83216E450117 | mysql_native_password |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

**Installation without root password**

Without a password, root@localhost uses the `auth_socket` plugin:

```
mysql> select host,user,authentication_string,plugin from mysql.user;
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| host      | user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| localhost | root             |                                           | auth_socket           |
| localhost | mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | *DA57FEBA9C5C5119186DB8834C7B83216E450117 | mysql_native_password |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

`auth_socket` only works if you're connecting from localhost through a unix_socket. It simply checks if the username making the connection **matches the username** in the 'user' field, **there is no password**.

That's why you can do `sudo mysql` and use any password you like, or none, but doing `mysql -u root -p` as an unprivileged user will never work, regardless of what password you type.

The Ansible module is currently unable to set a password unless the plugin is mysql_native_password, so you need to set the plugin value correctly first.

There's already a [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3003) for fixing this.

**Solution**

Install MySQL *with* a password, by using the [debconf module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debconf_module.html) to supply it in advance (you have to set it twice, once for the confirmation screen).  Then install MySQL, save the password to `/root/.my.cnf` so root user can connect automatically, and use mysql_user to set whatever other logins you need.

```
- hosts: myserver
  vars:
    mysql_root_password: foobarbaz

  tasks:
    - name: Specify MySQL root password before installing
      # without this, auth_socket will be used for root@localhost, and we won't be able to set the password
      debconf: name='mysql-server' question='mysql-server/root_password' value='{{mysql_root_password | quote}}' vtype='password'
      become: true

    - name: Confirm MySQL root password before installing
      debconf: name='mysql-server' question='mysql-server/root_password_again' value='{{mysql_root_password | quote}}' vtype='password'
      become: true

    - name: Install MySQL server
      apt: name={{ item }} state=present
      with_items:
        - mysql-server
        - python-mysqldb
      become: true

    - name: Start MySQL
      service: name=mysql state=started
      become: true

    - name: create /root/.my.cnf (from template) with password credentials
      template: src=/etc/ansible/templates/root/.my.cnf dest=/root/.my.cnf owner=root mode=0600
      become: true

    - name: update mysql root password for all root accounts
      mysql_user: name=root host={{ item }} password={{ mysql_root_password }} sql_log_bin=yes priv=*.*:ALL,GRANT
      with_items:
        - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
        - 127.0.0.1
        - ::1
        - "localhost"
      become: true
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach - but I'm not sure where you're getting the `/etc/ansible/templates/root/.my.cnf`. Admittedly I don't have ansible installed on the machine I'm installing to (I'm using ansible to provision a Vagrant VM), but at the same time i don't have this template on my local machine that does have ansible installed.

Comment: Ah - my bad, I just needed to read up on [ansible templates](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html).

Comment: @william-turrell can you specify the contents of your .my.cnf file?

Answer (score 9):

Since Ansible supports Unix domain socket for local connections now, there is pretty elegant way (without initial root user setup and any file config):

```
tasks:
  # assume that pymysql and mysql-server (with default config) are installed before this task

  - name: add user to mysql server
    mysql_user:
      # you can get socket path from /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
      login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  # default path
      name: username
      password: user_password
      priv: "database.*:ALL"    # not sure about dot, colon and asterisk, so I used quotes here
    become: yes
```

`login_unix_socket` parameter is available for all Ansible mysql modules ([v2.9](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/list_of_database_modules.html#mysql) | [v2.10+](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/index.html))

Answer (score 5):

Alternative solution:

`sudo mysql -u root -p{{ mysql_root_password }} -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '{{ mysql_root_password }}'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"`

It works the first time because root still uses the `auth_socket` authentication plugin and ignores the password, and for subsequent runs because the password will be correct.

Found the solution, with an explanation on how to debug here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/

Comment: N.B. This doesn't use the `mysql_user` ansible module.